# NSLog output no where to be found, Xcode8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I'm trying to use NSLog statements to figure out the execution flow of my app, so I have one in main.m right after autoreleasepool:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSLog(@"app started"); //added breakpoint here, but debugger stopped at next line
    BOOL runningTests = NSClassFromString(@"XCTestCase") != nil; //stopped here instead of nslog.
    ...
```

Now, that statement is no where to be found. I've tried searching the console, using 'command + /' to bring up a console for the simulator and searched through the system.log there but still nothing. To see if I was even going through main I added a breakpoint on the log statement and it was being hit, or at least the debugger stopped on the statement after the log (shown in code snippet). Is there something that I don't understand about the app life cycle, for example are the logs being cleared at some point when the application is launched? I also have other NSLog statements in other functions that I expect to be called but they aren't printed either. Why aren't my logs being printed to console?

Side notes:

My console is indeed active, and the output I'm looking at is 'All Output'.

Is there another way I can determine the execution flow of my application? It's a really large app with lots of storyboards and view controllers. By execution flow I mean which views are hit first, what functions are called from those views, how the app determines the next view when the app loads (depending on if the user is logged in) etc...

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
the pre-processor macros I have
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the line of code is being called? Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the line to see if it is being called.

Comment: @rmaddy Yea I did that, but I guess I was vague in my description as to where I added the breakpoint. I updated the code with the location of the breakpoint.

Comment: Is there some macro or something that is converting calls to `NSLog` to no-ops?

Comment: So yes I'm sure the code is being called. Or at least the line after it is being called haha.

Comment: How would I go about finding out if there was said macro?

Comment: Try this: view the .m file. Then click on the Product menu and select Perform Action then Preprocess whatever.m. Now search for `NSLog` in the resulting output.

Comment: I did it and there were not NSLog's in the resulting output.

Comment: Something is compiling out the NSLog calls. Not sure why.

Comment: I added an image of the pre-processor macros for my target, I don't think they're being compiled out because of something I'm doing, could it be a bug with xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to Andrew Veresov and rmaddy I was able to figure out the issue. The problem was that I had the Appstore scheme selected in product->scheme. I had to change it to the development scheme for all the logs to print. I'm not sure exactly how this works because some log statements still print even though others don't. If anyone can elaborate on schemes and how they work then I'd really appreciate it.

UPDATE: The issue was actually that the appstore scheme defined a macro that was getting rid of NSLogs:

```
#ifndef __OPTIMIZE__
#define NSLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define NSLog(...) {;}
#endif
```

So when I changed the scheme this macro was no longer being used, if you have this issue do as drekka said: "... do a global search for '#define NSLog' and see what comes up." You can remove the macro and your logs will show up.

Thanks a bunch drekka for pointing this out!

Comment: It won't be a scheme issue. It will be that a particular scheme is causing a macro to activate. My guess would be that somewhere in one of your pods there is a macro defined which overrides NSLog. I would do a global search for '#define NSLog' and see what comes up. Then I would get rid of that pod. Overriding NSLog like that is a bad idea.

Comment: You're absolutely right, there was a macro defined for the Appstore scheme that doesn't print log statements. Awesome answer.

Answer (score 1):

the NSlog is executed but is hidden among lots of other console debug outputs to solve this issue:

```
In Xcode8: 

Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments -> Environment Variables
```

add `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` and check it, but don't add any value.

Comment: hmm, try to set to the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE value  disable, also OS_ACTIVITY_MODE - w/o quotes